# Flutter - function outputs zero even though value from dbhelper is present

Tags: flutter, sqflite

I have an where i cant pass on the value obtained from my sqflight db to my method in a stateless function.
My db works and i obtain the right value which i checked through the print function no issue here.

for context in dbhelper:

```
  static Future <int>  getWaterDrank() async {
    final db = await WaterDBHelper.db();
     List result = await db.rawQuery(
        "SELECT * FROM $tableName WHERE ${columnDate} = ?", [dateCurrent]
    );
     print('this is the result $result');
    String waterDrank = result[0]
        .entries
        .firstWhere((element) => element.key == 'waterDrank')
        .value.toString();

    print('this is what we are after ${int.parse(waterDrank)}');

    return int.parse(waterDrank);
  }
```

this is my stateless widget, where there is this function in charge of deriving value from db. for some reason i get it as zero even though the print function in dbhelper displays a value.

```
  getWaterDrankStored()  async {
   int waterStoredValueInteger =  await WaterDBHelper.getWaterDrank();

    return waterStoredValueInteger;
  }
```

i am not sure what i am doing wrong.
[image]

Comment: By the way, It's recommended to name non-constant identifiers using lowerCamelCase. [learn more](https://dart.dev/tools/linter-rules/non_constant_identifier_names)

Comment: What does `print('this is the result $result');` print?

Answer (score 1):

I guess, your `GetWaterDrankStored()` method is returning something else, but not `int`. And you are getting an error when you are trying to call this method. Make sure your method returns `Future<int>`.

Comment: yeah i figured i did change it though where now i do receive an int from db but i cant pass that value on if you may check it out

Comment: can you provide a whole error message with all your print statements? And more code, maybe the file where you are calling getWaterDrankStored() method?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you did not provide a return value to your async method. This return value should be a future. Also the variable totalWaterDrank has an internal Scope inside the method. Please try this:

```
  Future<int> totalWaterDrank2;

  
    
  Future<int> addedWater()  async{
    int totalWaterDrank = await WaterButtonsGrouped().getWaterDrankStored();
    
    return  totalWaterDrank;
  }
    
    totalWaterDrank2 = addedWater();
```

Comment: thanks for looking into it but that wasnt an issue. I did move on if you would kindly give it another look to help me out

Comment: I tried the new version and it worked.